# Filehelpers Excel to Oracle db

Tags: asp.net, oracle, excel, file-upload, filehelpers

I want to import excel data to oracle DB.  I got enough help for Excel part, can you guys help me in Oracle side?

Is it possible to import to oracledb with [filehelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com)?  Please provide some sample code for reference.

Thanks 
Dee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you save the spreadsheet data as .csv files it is relatively straightforward to import it into Oracle using SQL*Loader or external tables.  Because we can use SQL with external tables they are generally eaiser to work with, and so are preferable to SQL*Loader in almost all cases.  SQL*Loader is the betterchoice when dealing with huuuuge amounts of data and when ultra-fast loading is paramount.

Find out more about external tables [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm).  You'll find the equivalent reference for SQL*Loader [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_concepts.htm#i1005437).

Answer (score 1):

A simple and relatively fool-proof way to do that for one-off tasks is to create a new column in the excel sheet, containing a formula like that:

```
="insert into foobar values('"&A1&"','"&A2&"');"
```

Copy that to all rows, then copy the whole column into an editor and run it in SQL*Plus or sql developer.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Sqlloader](http://www.oracleutilities.com/OSUtil/sqlldr.html) to upload data from CSV to Oracle DB.