# How to programmatically generate correct Oracle SQL

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

So, I have a  Winforms project in C# that needs to generate correct SQL and send it to the database using odp.net.   I can handle the C# part that does the string manipulations and such, but the actual query needs to be correct.

Unfortunately my training in SQL is actually for Microsoft T-SQL. The 'in' statement is a bit new to me.

So when I tried some different variations of a query I got different results. I need to know why and what I can do to get the correct results.

So here is one variation of the SQL code.

```
SELECT o.rid,
        o.tcode,
        o.dwave_id,
        o.cvarid,
        r.pmid
      FROM STREADM.router_opport o, SPROADM.RESP r
     WHERE o.tcode in (&touch_codes)
     and o.rid = r.rid
      AND is_active = 'Y'
    ORDER BY rid;
```

The absolutely correct results were given when one would run the above code in PL/SQL developer and then manually enter the values for the touch codes.

However as I am trying to automate this, I need to generate code. And I have run into 2 problems. The first being the 1000 limit for the in clause.  The other is strange results. So what would be the different between the code above and this code?

```
SELECT o.rid,
        o.tcode,
        o.dwave_id,
        o.cvarid,
        r.pmid
      FROM STREADM.router_opport o, SPROADM.RESP r
     WHERE o.tcode in ('code1','code2')
        OR o.tcode in ('code3','code4')
     and o.rid = r.rid
      AND is_active = 'Y'
    ORDER BY rid;
```

Is this any different from the below?

```
SELECT o.rid,
        o.tcode,
        o.dwave_id,
        o.cvarid,
        r.pmid
      FROM STREADM.router_opport o, SPROADM.RESP r
     WHERE o.tcode ='code1' 
        OR o.tcode ='code2'
        OR o.tcode ='code3'
        OR o.tcode ='code4'

     and o.rid = r.rid
      AND is_active = 'Y'
    ORDER BY rid;
```

Basically I need to know and understand what SQL code would generate the exactly same results as the first piece of code.

Comment: I see no PL/SQL aspects here, so I removed all PL/SQL references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say

> "And I have run into 2 problems ..... The other is strange results. "

Your second set of queries will not produce the same results as your original query because of Condition Precedence. [Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/conditions001.htm#SQLRF52103)

In short you are wantonly mixing OR and AND clauses, and Oracle is not evaluating them the way you think it is.  What you need to do is wrap all the OR clauses in an outer set of brackets, to show Oracle how to evaluate the conditions.  So ...

```
 WHERE
  ( 
    o.tcode in ('code1','code2')
    OR o.tcode in ('code3','code4')
   )
 and o.rid = r.rid
  AND is_active = 'Y'
```

... or ...

```
WHERE 
   (
    o.tcode ='code1' 
    OR o.tcode ='code2'
    OR o.tcode ='code3'
    OR o.tcode ='code4'
 )
  and o.rid = r.rid
  AND is_active = 'Y'
```

---

> "The input is read from an excel file."

The best method for importing data from such a source would be to export it from Excel as a CSV file (the source system which provides the data may be able to produce the extract in this format) and then use an external table to expose the data to the database.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/tablecls.htm#CNCPT1141).

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE o.tcode ='code1' 
    OR o.tcode ='code2'
    OR o.tcode ='code3'
    OR o.tcode ='code4'
```

is exactly equivalent semantically to

```
WHERE o.tcode in('code1', 'code2', 'code3', 'code4')
```

and

```
WHERE o.tcode in('code1', 'code2')
   OR o.tcode in('code3', 'code4')
```

That being said, I would be rather dubious about any solution that involved generating SQL statements with hard-coded literals rather than bind variables or any solution that generated `IN` lists with more than 1000 elements.  Where are those elements coming from?  Are they coming from a query?  Could you load them into a temporary table or a collection and reference that temporary table/ collection in your `select` statement?

Comment: No, my actual code does not use hard coded literals. Nor are those the exact table names either. The input is read from an excel file.

Comment: My training in SQL has been rather informal, as such I have not worked much with temp tables.

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett - The 1000 element limit only applies if you are using individual elements, not `select` statements.  If you're not using literals in your code, I would strongly suggest loading the data from the spreadsheet into a temporary table/ external table/ collection that you reference in your query.

Comment: So to be clear when I say it does not use literals, I mean it does not use hard coded values. Values are read as string from excel then as a result of string manipulation are inserted into a string representation of the query which is then programmatically sent to the database.  There are no 'code1' or whatever in my C# anywhere.

Comment: Instead it looks more like this     
                    for (int j = startingpoint; j < threshold * (1 + i); j++)
                     {
                            query.Append("'" + d.Value2[j][0] + "',");

                        }

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett - From the database's perspective, that is using literals.  Using literals is generally a poor approach-- it creates a bunch of non-sharable SQL statements that can overwhelm the shared pool and force Oracle to do a ton of hard parsing.

Comment: So, how would I load values into a temp table? And also wouldn't the values being loaded into the temp table be literals at the time of loading or otherwise require parsing at the time of loading?

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett See e.g. my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7683157/272735 how to use external tables. That should get you started.

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett, loading to a temp table (GTT) is very fast, especially if you use array inserts.  That + your select is much faster than having to compile a select statement with 1,000 literal values.  If you use a GTT, just make sure your insert and subsequent select are part of the same session, preferably the same transaction.  Each GTT exists within the scope of a session.